# Filter period of spring and spring security filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I know a servlet web requet will pass through:

```
request -> filter-1 -> filter-2 -> ... -> filter-n -> servlet
```

If I use spring, it is:

```
request -> filter-1 -> filter-2 -> filter-spring(DelegatingFilterProxy) -> ... -> filter-n -> servlet
```

If I define a Filter as bean, this bean will be included in filter-spring:

```
filter-spring(myFilter1 -> myFilter2...)
```

If I use spring-security, a Filter called FilterChainProxy created and be included in DelegatingFilterProxy:

```
filter-spring(myFilter1 -> filter-security(FilterChainProxy) -> myFilter2...)
```

If I define a security-filter, it will be added in FilterChainProxy:

```
filter-spring(myFilter1 -> filter-security(mySecurityFilter1 -> mySecurityFilter2 ...) -> myFilter2...)
```

My questions are:

- what is order of `filter-spring(DelegatingFilterProxy)` in global filters?
- what is order of `filter-security(FilterChainProxy)` in `filter-spring`?
- what is order of `myFilter1` and `myFilter2` in `filter-spring`, and how to define those order(before and behind `filter-security`)?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. There is no such `spring-filters(DelegatingFilterProxy)`. There are only servlet filters, Spring Security filter chains and Spring Security filter. All are implementing servlet's `Filter` interface. I gave you a link for the order of Spring Security filters. You will find order for Spring Security filter chains in the same documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**Servlet Filter**

You could set the order of your custom servlet filter with `@Order` annotation, `Ordered` interface or `FilterRegistrationBean`, see [Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.0/reference/htmlsingle/#features.developing-web-applications.embedded-container.servlets-filters-listeners.beans):

> It is usually safe to leave Filter beans unordered. If a specific order is required, you should annotate the `Filter` with `@Order` or make it implement `Ordered`. You cannot configure the order of a `Filter` by annotating its bean method with `@Order`. If you cannot change the `Filter` class to add `@Order` or implement `Ordered`, you must define a `FilterRegistrationBean` for the `Filter` and set the registration bean’s order using the `setOrder(int)` method.

**Security Filter Chain**

You could set the order of your custom security filter chain with `@Order`, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.1/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity):

> (2) Create an instance of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` that contains `@Order` to specify which `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should be considered first.

Default order is documented at [`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.1/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html).

**Security Filter**

You could set the order of your custom security filter with `addFilterAfter​`, `addFilterBefore`, see [`HttpSecurityBuilder#addFilterBefore`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilterBefore(javax.servlet.Filter,java.lang.Class)):

> Allows adding a `Filter` before one of the known `Filter` classes.

Default order is documented in [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.1/reference/html5/#servlet-security-filters).

Comment: Say I have CustomFilter1 with @Order(1) and CustomerFilter2 with @Order(2), then I added them in the security filter with addFilterBefore(customFilter2, CustomFilter1.class) which means CustomFilter2 going before CustomFilter1. How would that work?

Comment: @superigno I would say that `addFilterBefore` will take precedence, but I didn't try it.